# Ubuntu shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script that is supposed to run a program on ubuntu. If I double click it, it asks me what I want to do:

Run in terminal, Display, Cancel, Run.

If I choose Run in terminal, it works fine. But if I press Run, nothing happens. Why?

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rlwrap sicstus
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com is a great site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script does not start the terminal emulator.

If you choose "Run in terminal", a terminal emulator is started and the executable/script is connected to the terminal.

If you choose just "Run", the script will try to read from stdin and freezes because it is not connected to a terminal.

This might work and if it does it won't matter if you choose "Run in terminal" or just "Run".

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$TERM" ]; then
    x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c 'rlwrap sicstus; echo Press any key; read'"
else
    rlwrap sicstus
fi
```

Comment: This does not work. It doest indeed open a terminal, but it closes it immediately after

Comment: If `rlwrap sicstus` is not interactive, the edit I just made may work.

Answer (score 2):

`Run in terminal` - open a new terminal window and execute the given application / script so that you could see the output.
`Run` - execute the given application / script in background.
So, you won't get any output when running the script.

Comment: Is there a way to make run in terminal the default behavior on double click instead of Run then?

Comment: Open Nautilus, then go to Edit -> Preferences. Open Behavior tab and you'll find the options to set the file manager behavior when you open executable text files.

Comment: For knowing how to set this for single file. Please ask another question. The answer is irrelevent to this one.